# 401 authentication error when calling OpenWorkbook method of ExcelService.asmx 

Tags: 2007, development, excel-services, web-services

We are trying to call the Excel Services web service using SOAP with a Sharepoint/domain admin account.

I see 401.2 errors in the IIS logs.  There is no user name specified there.  We are using NTLM authentication.

Has anyone been able to connect to the web service and open a workbook successfully?  Any ideas on my authentication woes?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you using Claims Authentication? I am having a similar problem when I use mixed authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Had a situation which sounds similar to this a few months ago. One of the config features that I was using changed the order of the httpHandlers section of the config file. Try checking that the  element appear before all the "add" elements.

Comment: In the HttpHandlers section i have:
<remove verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*" />
<add verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="*" type="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpHandler, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
<add verb.. Type=Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationRuntime.SPHttpHandler

Comment: do you have 
<add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />?